# Display modified date in Recently Updated Post, Wp Query

Tags: php, wordpress

iam trying to display RECENTLY UPDATED Post Using Wp Query. Post and Title displaying Good, But Modified date not Displaying. Here is my Code. Please suggest me.

```
$loop = new WP_Query( [
        'posts_per_page'    => 6,
        'orderby' => 'modified',
'ignore_sticky_posts' => '1'
    ] );
    
    
    echo '<header><h class="updated-title updated">Recently Updated</h></header>';
    echo '<div class="recentlyupdated">';
    if( $loop->have_posts() ):
        
        while( $loop->have_posts() ):
            $loop->the_post();
            
        ?>
        <article class="recentlyupdatedposts">
        
        <div class="recent-updated-thumb">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
            </div>
            
        <span class="recent-updated-title">
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        </span>
        <span class="recently-mod-time"><?php get_the_modified_date() ?></span>
        </article>
<?php
            
        endwhile;
        echo '</div>';
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
```

Comment: Have you checked your html code to see if the date is there? perhaps it is there but it is hidden due to your html/css ? Although this shouldnt be the issue, you could try specifying the parameters for get_the_modified_date(format, post_id)

Comment: Yes checked. Theres no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `echo` [get_the_modified_date()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_modified_date/) function to print modified date. you can also check the format params. check below code.

```
$loop = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page'      => 6,
    'orderby'             => 'modified',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => '1'
] );


echo '<header><h class="updated-title updated">Recently Updated</h></header>';
echo '<div class="recentlyupdated">';
if( $loop->have_posts() ): while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post();
    ?>
    <article class="recentlyupdatedposts">
        <div class="recent-updated-thumb">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <span class="recent-updated-title">
            <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        </span>
        <span class="recently-mod-time"><?php get_the_modified_date() ?></span>
    </article>
<?php endwhile;
echo '</div>';
wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```